# Saving 2 forms which are associated by the models using saveAssociated()

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP Version 2.2.3

I want to save 2 forms on the same page using 2 associated models.
Model 1 : Proposal hasOne Client
Model 2 : Client belongsTo Proposal

Now here is my admin_edit action in my ProposalsController.php:

```
function admin_edit($id=null){
        $this->loadModel('Client');
        if ($this->request->is('put') || $this->request->is('Post')) {
            if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        // Use the following to avoid validation errors:
                unset($this->Proposal->Client->validate['proposal_id']);
                //$this->Proposal->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
                //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                debug($this->request->data);
            }
        }
        elseif($id){
            $this->Proposal->id = $id;
            $this->request->data = $this->Proposal->read();
        }

    }
```

I used the example found in the CakePHP book.

And here is my view admin_edit.ctp with the 2 forms:

```
<hr/>
<h1>Proposition</h1>
<hr/>

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Proposal'); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('Proposal.name', array('label' => "Nom de la proposition")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Proposal.created', array('label' => "Date de création")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Proposal.due', array('label' => "Date d'échéance")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Proposal.content', array('label' => "Termes & conditions")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Proposal.id'); ?>

<hr/>
<h1>Client</h1>
<hr/>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('Client.name', array('label' => "Nom du client")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Client.project', array('label' => "Nom du projet")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Client.address', array('label' => "Adresse")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Client.phone', array('label' => "Téléphone")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Client.email', array('label' => "Email")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden('Client.proposal_id'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Client.id'); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end('valider'); ?>
```

Also inspired from the CakePHP book.

The data is saved but for the second form all that it saves is a "`NULL`" value in each column of my clients table. But if I debug(request->data), I get all the data i've  entered the 2 forms. That's odd.

What is it that I don't do correctly?

Thank you very much for all your help!

**[EDIT]**: I have updated this post and corrected the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `Client.0.name` notation is only required for `hasMany` relationships, so you need to change it to: `Client.name`

Comment: Thank you very much enrmarc, that's was only that! I must have misread the book but again thanks a lot i really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently not at my computer, so am not able to check this, but:

Because you have a 'hasOne' relationship, not a 'hasMany', you should not use the .0. Naming for the second form. Look at the first example/explanation in the manual:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

So inputs for the second form will look like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Client.name', array('label' => "Nom du client")); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you thaJeztah for your enlightment it's working correctly now!
THanks a lot guys for your help :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck on your project!